# Azure automatic tuning and Entity Framework?

Tags: entity-framework, azure-sql-database

I have a small project with inherited C# code, specifically Entity Framework Core. This is hosted in Azure and recently I saw a very interesting feature that I would like to try out: "Automatic Tuning" for the database.

I have a couple of questions regarding this:

1. Would it conflict with my Entity Framework, as the database objects were originally created from code? My understanding is that it shouldn't, but I would like to be sure.
2. Is it worth it or anyone had any trouble with it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Automatic Tuning does not get in conflict in any way with Entity Framework (EF). It just create indexes needed by queries in use on your application. It also drops duplicated and unneeded indexes (but existent unique indexes are not dropped) and chooses the best query plan created by SQL Server. None of these are related to EF.

One thing you need to consider is that Azure SQL Database needs to monitor query activities at least for a day in order to identify some recommendations.

Another thing to take in consideration is that Automatic Tuning does not update statistics and does not defrag indexes.

Comment: This is incorrect. Automatic Tuning can cause migrations to fail by adding or removing indexes that EF does not know about.